# How to open my app out of sms app via sms link message?

Tags: android

Currently, tapping a URL to open my app works using the following code.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data
                android:host="www.waystride.com"
                android:path="/launch"
                android:scheme="https"></data>
        </intent-filter>
```

The trouble is that when I tap the link inside the sms app, my app is opened 'inside' sms app, unlike when I chose google chrome or other browser. I mean, when I tap 'app switcher' icon, my app is shown in 'Messages/SMS' app. (Samsung S9 & Moto G5Plus)

The reason that I need to fix this is because my app uses GPS, within Messages/SMS app, my app couldn't get GPS location info. Thanks in advance!

I couldn't find answer for this either 1) it is hard to search the problem 2) I am not good at search stack overflow. But anyway, this is important...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "singleTask" launch mode. You can specify it in the AndroidManifest for your activity which contains the intent filter.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   >
...
</activity>
```

You can read more here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#TaskLaunchModes

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked great! the link was helpful, too. I upvote your answer, but since my points is so low... 
Also this is useful: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)